# c++ terminate std::logic error ......where did my code go wrong?

Tags: c++

I'm encountering this really weird error and I dont know where I'm constructing a string with a null parameter, could someone please help me out? Thanks!

Here's the error:
terminate_called_after_throwing_an_instance_of_'std::logic_error'
__what():__basic_string::_M_construct_null_not_valid
Here's my code:

```
/*
ID: 2005amr1
TASK: friday 
LANG: C++                 
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector <string> days = {"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};


bool leap (int y){
    if (y%100 == 0){
        if (y%400 == 0){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (y%4 == 0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

int targetedSearch (vector<string> array, string key){
     int index = 0;  
     while( (index < array.size( )) && (key != array[index])){
        if (array[index] != key){
         index++;
         }
      }
      return (index); 
}

string findLastDay(string FDAY, int daysInMonth){ // all good here
    int indexOfString = targetedSearch(days, FDAY);
    if (FDAY == "Mon" && daysInMonth == 28){
        return ("Sun");
    }
    return (days[(daysInMonth - (7*(daysInMonth/7))-1) + indexOfString]);
}

string find13Day (string firstDay){ // all good here
    int indexOfString = targetedSearch(days, firstDay);
    return (days[indexOfString+5]);
}

string findFirstDayNextMonth (string LDAY){
    int indexOfString = targetedSearch(days, LDAY);
    if (indexOfString+1 > 6){
        return (days[(indexOfString+1)-7]);
    }
    else{
    return (days[indexOfString+1]);
}
}
int numDays (int month, int year){
    switch(month) {
      
      case 0:
        return 31;
        break;
      
      case 1:
        if (leap(year) == true){
            return 29;
        }
        else{
            return 28;
        }
        break;
      
      case 2:
            return 31;
            break;
      
      case 3:
            return 30;
            break;
      
      case 4:
            return 31;
            break;

      case 5:
            return 30;
            break;
      
      case 6:
            return 31;
            break;
      
      case 7:
            return 31;
            break;
      
      case 8:
            return 30;
            break;
      
      case 9:
            return 31;
            break;
      
      case 10:
            return 30;
            break;

      case 11:
            return 31;
            break;

    }
    return 31;
}



int main() {
    ofstream fout ("friday.out");
    ifstream fin ("friday.in");
    string startDay = "Mon";
    int dayValues[7] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int n;
    fin >> n;
    map <string,int> dayValue;
    for (int i = 1900; i< 1900+n; i++){
        for (int m =0; m<12; m++){
            int PAN = numDays (m,i);
            string tday = find13Day(startDay);
            dayValues[targetedSearch(days,tday)]++;
            string LDAY = findLastDay(startDay, PAN);
            startDay = findFirstDayNextMonth(LDAY);
        }
    }
    fout << " " << dayValues[5] << " " << dayValues[6]<< " " << dayValues[0]<< " " << dayValues[1]<< " " << dayValues[2]<< " " << dayValues[3]<< " " << dayValues[4];
    
    }
```

Comment: One problem I see is in `find13Day`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm hm I see.  I tried troubleshooting by cutting down pieces of code in a for loop and found that the line of code startDay = findFirstDayNextMonth(LDAY) was causing me trouble, do you think something could have caused the error there?

Comment: `findLastDay` has a similar problem.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm and what would that problem be? I'm fairly new to programming and want to learn as much as I can.

Comment: Consider: if `firstDay` is "Thu" when you call `find13Day`, what value will be returned?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm It would first find the index at which "Thu" is at, and it would show 5 indexes afterwards but that would be out of bounds....oh i see now, thank you for pointing that out

Comment: You might consider stepping through your code in a debugger so you can see how it works and how that is different than how you expect it to work.